# Two text boxes and many buttons python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to press a button and have it print the location of the cursor X/Y coordinates as well as the content of the button in tkinter.

I'm new to python and I haven't found any way to do this. Can anyone help me finding the right start on this issue?

Comment: Look up pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bind the button click `event` to print the location clicked, here's an example of how you can do that.

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_location(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='click me')
button.bind("<Button-1>", print_location)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note: using external modules such as pyautogui is not recommended and unnecessary.

Comment: What I want to do is that where the cursor is (|), if I press a button I will see what is in the button
I leave you my code if you could help me

Comment: That's not what SO is for, we're here to help you debug your error, not write code for people. Sorry.

Comment: import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='1')
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='2')
button2.pack()
BOX1=Entry()
BOX1.pack()
BOX2=Entry()
BOX2.pack()
root.mainloop()